# QNetworkAccessManager sends RST, ACK packet

Tags: qt, tcp, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork

in my application I have one instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` which is used for sending and receiving all network traffic. The traffic consists exclusively of HTTP GET requests and responses.

Currently I have hardcoded so that the application sends a request every 10 seconds, and I noticed in Windows resource monitor that it keeps establishing new connections upon every request.
Finding that strange I added the header `Connection: Keep-Alive` to every outgoing request, but it still establishes a new connection on every request.

Here is a complete Wireshark capture for one request/response cycle:

```
+-----------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+
| Timestamp | Source | Destination | Info                    |
+-----------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+
| 0.000000  | client | server      | SYN                     |
| 0.020673  | server | client      | SYN, ACK(1)             |
| 0.020810  | client | server      | ACK(1)                  |
| 0.021529  | client | server      | HTTP GET request        |
| 0.081772  | server | client      | ACK(286)                |
| 0.083658  | server | client      | HTTP 200 OK (with data) |
| 0.133877  | client | server      | ACK(286)                |
| 5.081253  | server | client      | FIN, ACK(286)           |
| 5.081449  | client | server      | ACK(1072)               |
| 5.081606  | client | server      | RST, ACK(1072)          |
+-----------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

As can be seen in the table, the server sends FIN, ACK after 5 seconds of inactivity, and the client (QNetworkAccessManager I suppose?) responds with ACK **and** RST, ACK and the connection is closed, even though I've set the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header.

I'm no expert in TCP communication, so I'm not really sure what it means that the client sends RST, ACK.

My question is: Is this a client or server side issue? What can be done to ensure the connection is kept alive?

Thanks in advance!